# Visio 2013 - How to create Supertype/Subtype?

Tags: visio

For a class I am in, I need to create an ERD in Visio, using Crow's Foot notation.  This is all fine, and works well enough.  However, now I need also model a supertype (and eventually a subtype).  This functionality, if it exists in Visio 2013, seems hidden.  Has anyone been able to do this?  My friend Google was not very helpful, as every tutorial for this seems to be in Visio 2010.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature was discontinued in the 2013 version, unfortunately. Visio 2010 is the only one that has it.

Comment: Can someone please provide an alternative tool that allows for some functions of the EERD such as subtype/supertype relationship? I have been looking everywhere and the only one i could find was LucidCharts but i believe you have to have the PRO subscription.